# borders slightly misaligned

Tags: html, css, border

For an odd reason, my 6 borders seem a little garbled.

Here's an image: [image: Issue]

Here's my chunk of CSS for that list:

```
#aboutcontent #names li{
    width: 325px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

I'd like all those borders touching perfectly, no space in between.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ray6pgut/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `ul` `font-size: 0` or remove whitespaces between li. Inline-block elements considers the whitespaces too. You can read about this [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

```
<li></li>...<li></li>  // remove whitespace between li
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ray6pgut/2/)

Or

```
#aboutcontent #names{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ray6pgut/3/)

Comment: @ anpsmn, sorry my fault..perfect answer...:)

Comment: i hate css. changing font size perfectly fixed my image misalignment issues

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#aboutcontent #names li{
    width: 325px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    float:left;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 0 7px 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seen on css-tricks.com

The most easy way.
Close the li tag on the next line! It seem wired, but it really works.

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li
  ><li>two</li
  ><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left;` instead of `inline-block` in your `#aboutcontent #names li`

**CSS:**

```
#aboutcontent #names li{    
    float:left;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ray6pgut/1/)**

Comment: @ Etash, to add float:left, you also have to add clear:both to end of ul but float:left is not good answer as it will remove the centre property of all 6 div.m just thinking to do that without moving center to left.